# What is best option to to create custom database table while developing WordPress Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to develop a New WordPress Plugin, I have tried to store the settings values in the WordPress built in DB table Options but there is problem storing and fetching the values so i decided to create new database table to store the values, Is this a good idea to create new db table and what is best way to create, sanitize and retrieve the valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than write to the Wordpress tables directly, use the Wordpress APIs that serialize your data and write it correctly. The [add_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/) function and the similar get_option function should be what you are looking for.

Comment: i have a options in my plugins that works this was.

1. use the css styles that are used in default theme styles

2. there is option to create custom global styles that apply for different copies of widgets of same plugin

3. and there is option to crete custom css style for individual widgets of same plugin

and the issue occurs here is: if user have set the global style css and each global styles need to automatically store in individual widgets settings too.

so please suggest me how it works and best way to create db table or use its own add_option function to store the datas